# Como referenciar um botão html em C#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, navegador-de-internet, html-tags

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código em HTML :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este código pertence a uma página de um rádio Air OS (internet a rádio).

Preciso referenciar este botão dentro de um programa feito em Windows Forms e fazer uma função para que ele seja executado e o rádio seja reiniciado.

Só consegui pegar elementos com atributo de id, da seguinte forma:

```
HtmlElement username = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username");
```

Como faço para referenciar este botão que não possuí campo "id"? Lembrando que o código HTML não é meu, não posso editá-lo e colocar o campo "id".

Atualmente estou utilizando o componente WebBrowser, teria alguma outra forma de acessar o rádio e reiniciar sem usar o WebBrowser?

Obrigado.

Comment: <input ID="username" value="Yes, reboot!" type="submit">

Comment: Não posso alterar o código HTML, ele não é meu.

Comment: Tem que postar mais do HTML. Você vai ter que trabalhar explorando a hierarquia. Digo, vai ser necessário encontrar algum elemento "chave" e ir obtendo os filhos. Também, tente [edit] e ser mais específico na sua pergunta, parece que você tá falando de ASP.NET MVC, eu só entendi que você quer manipular por um web browser porque sou acostumado a lidar com WinForms.

Comment: editei a pergunta, estou utilizando windowsforms e o componente webbrowser para realizar esta tarefa.

Comment: Só faltou postar mais partes do HTML. Dessa forma não dá pra ajudar...

Comment: Postei todo o código agora

Comment: O texto "**Yes, reboot**" será sempre este?

Comment: será sim! o código HTML não muda.

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer desta forma :

```
var button = myWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
         .Cast<HtmlElement>()
         .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("type") == "submit");
```

Comment: deu certo! obrigado amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar pegar esse "botão" pelo tipo..

`var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');`

Nesse caso você tem os *inputs* da tela. Isso pode dar errado se você tiver mais *inputs* além do que você quer selecionar, aí precisaria de algum (outro) identificador único.